# How prove this inequality with $\sqrt{\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^2}{b^2}}+\sqrt{3}\ge\sqrt{\sum\frac{a}{b}}+\sqrt{\sum\frac{b}{a}}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $a,b,c>0$, show that
>   $$\sqrt{\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}+\dfrac{b^2}{c^2}+\dfrac{c^2}{a^2}}+\sqrt{3}\ge\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{b}{a}+\dfrac{c}{b}+\dfrac{a}{c}}$$
>   I tried C-S, AM-GM, Holder and more, but without success.

following maybe is idea:$$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{a}=x\Longrightarrow  x^2=\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{a^2}{b^2}+2\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{b}{a}$$
then How can prove this inequality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $\frac{a}{b}=x$, $\frac{b}{c}=y$ and $\frac{c}{a}=z$.

Hence, $xyz=1$ and we need to prove that
$$\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}+\sqrt{3}\geq\sqrt{x+y+z}+\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}.$$
 or
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3+2\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq x+y+z+xy+xz+yz+2\sqrt{(xy+xz+yz)}$$ or
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3-2(xy+xz+yz)+2\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}-2(x+y+z)+$$
$$+\left(\sqrt{xy+xz+yz}-\sqrt{x+y+z)}\right)^2\geq0,$$
which is true because by C-S
$$\sqrt{3(x^2+y^2+z^2)}=\sqrt{(1^2+1^2+1^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)}\geq x+y+z$$ and by Schur and by AM-GM we obtain:
$$x^2+y^2+z^2+3=\sum_{cyc}\left(\left(x^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)^3+x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}}z^{\frac{2}{3}}\right)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}\left(x^{\frac{4}{3}}y^{\frac{2}{3}}+x^{\frac{2}{3}}y^{\frac{4}{3}}\right)\geq\sum_{cyc}2xy=2(xy+xz+yz).$$
Done!

Comment: have simple methods?

Comment: @inequality But it's very simple! I am ready to answer any question.

Comment: the last why is obvious? can you explain more detali?Thanks

Comment: @inequality I have deleted my first solution for you and I explained. See now please.

Comment: Nice!+1,It's very nice!